# independence of x/y and y given that x and y are not independent

Tags: probability, random, independence

Suppose two non-negative random variates x and y are NOT independent (in my case that I am interested in, the range of x is constrained by y, i.e., $0<x\leq y$).

In more specific, assuming $y$ follows a uniform distribution $U(0,100)$ while $x$ is always $\leq y$,
so now is $z=x/y$ independent of y? why? can you provide a proof or reference for this?

My idea is that probability distribution function for z should be derived. here z has a range $0<z\leq1$.

For testing independence of y and z, we should prove that $f(z,y)=f(z) \cdot f(y)$. But I did not have a clue on it.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it?

Comment: Also, don't get discouraged by the downvote. I downvoted the question and voted to close it because at the moment, it is not up to site standards (you have shown no work you did on your own). If you edit your question so that you show what you tried and how far you got, I will not only remove the downvote, I will add the upvote.

Comment: Thanks, 5xum, I have tried to express my idea as detail as possible already.

Comment: Generally it is not true, z and y are not independent. It could be so for specific random variables x and y. So you have to tell the distribution functions of x and y and then you can determine if z and y are independant or not.

Comment: One example is to take $x = y$. Then of course, $z =x/y = 1$ is independent of $y$. Another example is to take $x = y^2$, where we assume that the random variable $y$ takes only values in $(0,1)$. Then $z = x/y = y$ is not independent of $y$. Thus, without further information one cannot say more than "independence as well as dependence are possible".

Comment: thanks, hvdrung and @PhoemueX. Does it mean that the relation between z and y is determined by the distribution functions of x and y?